# How do I adjust autocomplete list width

Tags: ajax, theming

Has anyone been successful in adjusting autocomplete list width (entity reference tag style)? I have hard time grabbing the element in Inspector/Firebug.
The goal is to have the width wider than the field that it's bound to, so to accommodate entire item label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As coded in autocomplete.js file inside misc folder, popup is wrapped inside

```
<div id="autocomplete"></div>
```

You can able to set width using above id. If you want to disable hide popup option for time being to style the popup results, then try commenting lines shown below in autocomplete.js file inside misc folder of your drupal root.

```
/**
 * Hides the autocomplete suggestions.
 */
Drupal.jsAC.prototype.hidePopup = function (keycode) {
  // Select item if the right key or mousebutton was pressed.
  if (this.selected && ((keycode && keycode != 46 && keycode != 8 && keycode != 27) || !keycode)) {
    this.input.value = $(this.selected).data('autocompleteValue');
  }
  // Hide popup.
  var popup = this.popup;
  if (popup) {
    this.popup = null;
    $(popup).fadeOut('fast', function () { $(popup).remove(); });
  }
  this.selected = false;
  $(this.ariaLive).empty();
};
```

**NOTE: Remove commented code** once styling is done. Clear the cache after making javascript changes and make sure changes are reflected in autocomplete.js file using firebug. Clear browser cache.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. The only point where I disliked the way the things are is that I had to apply that change for the admin side only directly in the Seven css. That's because the change was requested for admin pages only. This means that I will have to take a note of that change and re-apply when updating Drupal.